# Simple Auto login for linkedin Javascript api

Tags: javascript, authentication, linkedin-api, page-refresh

Hello fellow developers,

I've search the web more then sufficient to answer to the problem i'm having, needless to say I haven't found a solution ... yet. ( Also here on StackOverflow, there is no post or 'solution' that fixes my problem )

Simple as it is, i'm trying to get the auto-login to work for the linked-in api. My understanding of o-auth for linkedin tells me that the code beneath should do the trick, but it doesn't :( every refresh after granting acces results in a login-button reappearing.

Any insights ?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>LinkedIn</title>
<meta name="description" content="LinkedIn API Tryout">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: 7742sti7gm0bsk
authorize: true
</script>

</head>

<body>
<script type="in/Login">
Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It wasn't a matter of code, but rather of keeping your linkedin settings up to date while developing.

Sir Lee Fu, of LinkedIn, answered to the problem I was having:

> Could you please try to remove the application from the member's applications and try again? 
>   (its under settings)

This did the trick!